# MPMoviePlayerController switching videos

Tags: ios, swift, video

I'm playing a video:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Video", ofType:"mp4")
let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
if let player = moviePlayer {
    player.view.frame = self.view.bounds
    player.prepareToPlay()
    player.scalingMode = .AspectFill
    player.controlStyle = .None
    self.view.addSubview(player.view)
}
```

and I want to replace this with another video when a button is pressed:

```
@IBAction func aButtonIsPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Another Video", ofType:"mp4")
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
    moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
    if let player = moviePlayer {
        player.view.frame = self.view.bounds
        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.scalingMode = .AspectFill
        player.controlStyle = .None
        self.view.addSubview(player.view)
    }
}
```

When I tap the button the video plays, but there seems to be a delay adding the new video, which gives it a choppy transition. Is there any way to minimize this delay? I could try adding another MPMoviePlayerController to preload the second video maybe but from some testing I found the line causing the chop is here.

```
self.view.addSubview(player.view)
```

Can I keep the first video playing until the line above 'didFinish'? That would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new `MPMoviePlayerController` object that's why you are getting this issue, you should use same object and which is already playing an object and just set `contentURL` property to new resource's `URL`,

> If you set this property while a movie is playing, that movie pauses
>   and the new movie begins loading. The new movie starts playing at the
>   beginning

For more detail visit this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMoviePlayerController/contentURL)

Comment: Good stuff! Is there any way to preload on the same object? There is still a black screen that appears as the movie loads.

Comment: No you can't do that, but you can listen to stateChangeNotification and can show image on top or buffering animation until next start